# How to disable InMemoryCache for Apollo GraphQL client?

Tags: apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I am trying to completely disable caching on the apollo-client but its not working.

I have tried to set the *fetchPolicy* to 'network-only' or 'no-cache'. Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just remove the persistor whenever you need to clean the cache.

```
  const persistor = new CachePersistor({ cache: this.cache, storage: window.sessionStorage as any });
  await persistor.remove();
```